# Why does async socket cannot accept 1 more clients on python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I tried to make async socket core for my private server for game. This works, but don't accept more than 1 client. 2 clients trying to connect, but second client cannot do this, only when first will disconnect.

```
import asyncio, socket, time
class Server:
    def __init__(self, port: int):
        self.server = socket.socket()
        self.port = port
    async def start(self):
        self.server.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port))
        self.server.listen()
        print(f"Server started on {self.port}!")
        while True:
            session, ip = self.server.accept()
            print(f"{ip[0]} connected!")
            await Connection(session, ip[0]).messaging()
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, session, ip):
        self.session =  session
        self.ip = ip
    def receive(self, session, lens):
        data = b""
        while len(data) < lens:
            s = session.recv(lens)
            if not s:
                s += 0
                break
            data += s
        return data
    async def messaging(self):
        last = int(time.time())
        while True:
            try:
                header = self.session.recv(7)
                if len(header) > 0:
                    last = int(time.time())
                    mtype = int.from_bytes(header[:2], "big")
                    mlen = int.from_bytes(header[2:5], "big")
                    mdata = self.receive(self.session, mlen)
                    print(f"[C] {mtype} from {self.ip}")
                    if int(time.time()) - last > 7:
                        break
            except(ConnectionAbortedError, ConnectionResetError, ConnectionRefusedError, TimeoutError, OSError):
                break
        self.session.close()
        print(f"{self.ip} disconnected!")
asyncio.run(Server(9339).start())
```

I tried to use module select but this has laggy disconnect.

Comment: You should change server.listen() to server.listen(16) or something.

Comment: There is no await expression in your function `messaging.`  Once `messaging` begins to run no other task can proceed.  Tasks cooperate with one another by returning control to the event loop at an `await` expression; if you don't have an await expression then the current task keeps control.  No second task can get created until the first task breaks out of the while loop in `messaging`.